# Visual Studio 2010 Professional, is it legal to install on a second pc?

Tags: installation, license, visual-studio

Suppose you have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed on the desktop pc and also want to install it on a laptop to have it available when traveling.
Is this legal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in Germany a MS Visual Studio licence is per user, not per PC - thus this is legal.
You may check if your local policies differ.

Comment: As is true in the UK - if the license is part of the MSDN. This is why I can have it at work, home and on travel.

Answer (score 0):

You may have multiple installs provided that you don't have multiple *users*.